# Particles don't auto refresh using paint maps

Tags: animation, particles, dynamic-paint

So I was following CG Geek's tutorial on how to animate rain and splash effects and I was able to follow successfully until I had to animate the splash effects. The splash effect's density is controlled by an image sequence of paintmaps which is supposed to cycle through. But even during the render it doesn't.

frame 70:
[image]

frame 71:
[image]

I've set it to cyclic and auto refresh too:

[image]

Comment: Is the image sequence used in a ImageTexture node, too? Just asking because this node has also a *Auto Refresh* checkbox.

Comment: It's a bug. See this question for a solution: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/240694/107598