# Can`t get my raindrops to make a splash on the floor

Tags: particles

For the past couple of days, I have been breaking my head to solve this issue.The problem is that whenever a raindrop in my scene falls to the ground it doesn`t make a splash(the raindrops are emitted from the plane at the top)
[image]

So basically I made the splash by using planes with the texture of an image of a splash like this and put them into a collection by pressing 'ctrl+G'
[image]

Then I added a particle system to the plane on which the raindrops falls. I used the hair particle type, not the emitter.

[image]

And I made the object to render as a collection and then I chose the instance collection as the collection of the 'splash' planes.

[image]

Next, I added a new texture>went to the texture properties tab>added all the images of the wet map I created using Dynamic print physics(this makes the raindrops leave a white mark on the floor and then fade away after some time).
[image]

Something like this
[image]

Then I checked the 'cyclic' and 'Auto-refresh' options,changed the mapping coordinated to UV,selected the map and under the influence I selected the 'density' option instead of 'general time'

[image]

[image]

And when I play the animation the planes with the splash texture stays stationary throughout the whole animation.

[The link to the tutorial I am following in youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35bbyAJodEQ)

[Download the blend file over here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FHHExEolvcqiDmSQEE7xswwO8vq6r3hc/view)

**Update**

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130585/discussion-on-question-by-ribbit12-cant-get-my-raindrops-to-make-a-splash-on-th).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some known old bugs in the particle system and this seems to be one of them. The distribution of (hair) particles with image textures is kinda bugged.

When you use an *Image Sequence* to distribute the particles it looks like Blender uses only the current image at the current frame only at the moment when the particle settings are updated to calculate the possible spots for the particles. This calculation is not updated when the animation runs.

For the rain example here this means, when you're at frame 1 there are no particles hitting the road and the density texture is empty (=black). In consequence, you will see no splashes for the whole animation because Blender used the first empty image for the whole animation to calculate possible spots for the particles and never updated it.

On the other hand, when you're for example at frame 130 and update the particle system by changing something then Blender uses the 130th image of the sequence to distribute the splashes. This image has some white dots on it and is used for the whole animation. In consequence, you will see only around frame 130+ a few splashes because here the images have some white spots (=density weight for the particles).

The bug also causes to freeze the particle splashes now and then during the whole animation.

The mowing/shaving animation I made a while ago worked because it starts with a full density image. At least as long you're at frame 1 when you change things. The problems then occur at higher frames.

## How to Fix the Animation with the Bug?

Knowing this is quite simple to prevent the bug.

- in the timeline go to a frame where you have a full density map = a white image = "frame X". If there is no such a frame (like in this rain example here) then just paint the first image completely white and go to frame 1 (="frame X"). For the final animation, you will drop this dummy frame, of course.
- make sure you have enough particles. It looks like Blender distributes them all at the moment of the update and then filters them with help of the images sequence when the animation runs. Even if there are only 500 filtered particles visible at a given time you need all e.g. 50000 at the beginning of the calculation.
- update the particle physics by disabling and enabling it immediately again in the viewport by clicking the "eye" icon
- if you need to change the particle system repeat these steps to initialize it properly

**Example: Preparation for the particle update**

Go to frame 1 at the timeline. Make sure there are 50,000 particles and image 1 is painted completely white. Then disable and enable the particle system in the viewport to see all particles at the same time. This state Blender will use to filter/manipulate the particles with help of the image sequence.
[image: preparation for the particle update]

**Example: Testing the animation**

The setting *Texture Settings > Influence* has `[X] Density` and `[X] Hair Length` enabled. Run the animation. Here is frame 47 of the animation, the particles are visible and animated :-)

[image: frame 47 of the animation]

**Wet Road on a Rainy Day Animation**

First, the particles are selected to see the planes. Then they are unselected to see the final animation:

[image: wet road on a rainy day animation]

Comment: Thank you so much but it still isn`t working for me :( I think I am doing something wrong. I have updated the current status of my project after following your method.Could you share your file that you modified  so I can correct my project

Comment: Oh darn! Here is the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A3KnTt0BoJeWFUa-TSXOr0Lnhu9Pfqjx/view?usp=sharing The images are not included because it's 900 MB. Try File > External Data > Find Missing Files to fix the path. Hope that helps!

Comment: great!thanks so much

Comment: @Blunder ... Holly goodness !!! All those years of pain just for a "white frame" ??? It hurts even more now :) Thanks for such discovery. I'm going to test with Vertex Weight ...